# Multiword arguments from backtick (command substitution)

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a file `params.txt` containing the content

```
--option "option 1" --option "option 2"
```

I'd like to be able to use the contents of `params.txt` as the command-line arguments for some program, `myProg`:

```
./myProg $(cat params.txt)
```

or

```
./myProg `cat params.txt`
```

But that doesn't seem to work: it treats the multi-word arguments as multiple arguments, instead of single quoted arguments. Is there a way to use command substitution (or some other bash feature I don't know about) to pull the arguments from `params.txt` and get

```
./myProg --option "option 1" --option "option 2"
```

as the executed command?

Comment: Is `params.txt` being written by a human or a piece of software?

Comment: ...if it's coming from software, the best choice is to make it NUL-delimited, not shell-quoted.

Comment: Thanks. It's being written by a human. If it were NUL-delimited, would there be a way to use it easily in bash? EDIT: just saw the update to your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `params.txt` is written by a human you trust, you can do this with `eval`:

```
eval "./myProg $(<params.txt)"
```

To safely write an `eval`-safe stream from a script would look instead like the following:

```
printf '%q ' --option "option 1" --option "option 2" >params.txt
```

---

The better way to store parameters unambiguously, and use them without [the serious security risks caused by `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), is as a NUL-delimited stream:

```
# write params file
printf '%s\0' --option "option 1" --option "option 2" >params
```

...and then, to consume that...

```
# read params file into array
params=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' param; do
  params+=( "$param" )
done <params

# use that array to call your program
./myProg "${params[@]}"
```

Note that this latter form is not compatible with command substitution, but *can* be used with process substitution, if you're reading output from a command more interesting than `cat` (which is best replaced with a simple redirection). Thus:

```
# this does not work: depends on NULs being stored in a shell variable
while IFS= read -r -d '' param; do params+=( "$param" ); done <<<"$(...command here...)"

# this works
while IFS= read -r -d '' param; do params+=( "$param" ); done < <(...command here...)
```

Note that process substitution is functionality not present in POSIX sh; be sure your shebang specifies a shell (such as `#!/bin/bash`) with this support.